# Samsung Health : solving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: heart_rate (READ) is invalid

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

what I want to do is developing an app that reads health data that collected by Samsung watch so I tried to use Samsung android health SDK . Moreover reading steps was very easy as there was a sample app doing the same thing . the issue appear when I was trying to read the heart rate value :

here is my code please help me address the issue :

Mainfest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.smaunghealth">
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.health.permission.read"
                   android:value="com.samsung.health.step_count;com.samsung.health.heart_rate"/>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.smaunghealth;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String APP_TAG = "SimpleHealth";

    private static MainActivity mInstance = null;
    private HealthDataStore mStore;
    private HealthConnectionErrorResult mConnError;
    private Set<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey> mKeySet;
    private StepCountReporter mReporter;
    private HeartRateReporter mHeartReporter;

    TextView stepCount ;
    TextView heartRate ;


    private final HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult> mPermissionListener =
            new HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(HealthPermissionManager.PermissionResult result) {
                    Log.d(APP_TAG, "Permission callback is received.");
                    Map<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey, Boolean> resultMap = result.getResultMap();

                    if (resultMap.containsValue(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                        // Requesting permission fails
                    } else {
                        // Get the current step count and display it
                    }
                }
            };


    private final HealthDataStore.ConnectionListener mConnectionListener = new HealthDataStore.ConnectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConnected() {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is connected.");
            HealthPermissionManager pmsManager = new HealthPermissionManager(mStore);


            try {
                // Check whether the permissions that this application needs are acquired
                Map<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey, Boolean> resultMap = pmsManager.isPermissionAcquired(mKeySet);

                if (resultMap.containsValue(Boolean.FALSE)) {
                    // Request the permission for reading step counts if it is not acquired
                    pmsManager.requestPermissions(mKeySet, MainActivity.this).setResultListener(mPermissionListener);
                } else {
                    // Get the current step count and display it
                    // ...

                    mReporter = new StepCountReporter(mStore);
                    mReporter.start(mStepCountObserver);

                    mHeartReporter = new HeartRateReporter(mStore);
                    mHeartReporter.start(heartRateObserver);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(APP_TAG, e.getClass().getName() + " - " + e.getMessage());
                Log.e(APP_TAG, "Permission setting fails.");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(HealthConnectionErrorResult error) {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is not available.");
            showConnectionFailureDialog(error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Health data service is disconnected.");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mInstance = this;

        stepCount= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.step_count);
        heartRate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heart_rate);

        mKeySet = new HashSet<HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey>();
//        mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));
        mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));

        HealthDataService healthDataService = new HealthDataService();
        try {
            healthDataService.initialize(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}

        mStore = new HealthDataStore(this, mConnectionListener);
        // Request the connection to the health data store
        mStore.connectService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mStore.disconnectService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private StepCountReporter.StepCountObserver mStepCountObserver = count -> {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Step reported : " + count);
        updateStepCountView(String.valueOf(count));
    };

    private HeartRateReporter.HeartRateObserver  heartRateObserver = count -> {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "Step reported : " + count);
        updateHeartRateView(String.valueOf(count));
    };

    private void updateHeartRateView(String valueOf) {
        Log.d(APP_TAG, "heart rate reported : " + valueOf);
        updateHeartRateView(String.valueOf(valueOf));
    }

    private void updateStepCountView(String count) {
        stepCount.setText(count);

    }

    private void showConnectionFailureDialog(HealthConnectionErrorResult error) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mConnError = error;
        String message = "Connection with Samsung Health is not available";

        if (mConnError.hasResolution()) {
            switch(error.getErrorCode()) {
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.PLATFORM_NOT_INSTALLED:
                    message = "Please install Samsung Health";
                    break;
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.OLD_VERSION_PLATFORM:
                    message = "Please upgrade Samsung Health";
                    break;
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.PLATFORM_DISABLED:
                    message = "Please enable Samsung Health";
                    break;
                case HealthConnectionErrorResult.USER_AGREEMENT_NEEDED:
                    message = "Please agree with Samsung Health policy";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "Please make Samsung Health available";
                    break;
            }
        }

        alert.setMessage(message);

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                if (mConnError.hasResolution()) {
                    mConnError.resolve(mInstance);
                }
            }
        });

        if (error.hasResolution()) {
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        }

        alert.show();
    }
}
```

HeartRateReporter

```
package com.example.smaunghealth;

import android.util.Log;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.*;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class HeartRateReporter {

    private final HealthDataStore mStore;
    private HeartRateObserver mHeartRateObserver;
    private static final long ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;

    public HeartRateReporter(HealthDataStore store) {
        mStore = store;
    }

    public void start(HeartRateObserver listener) {
        mHeartRateObserver = listener;
        HealthDataObserver.addObserver(mStore, HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE, mObserver);
        readHeartRate();
    }

    private void readHeartRate() {
        HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(mStore, null);

        // Set time range from start time of today to the current time
        long startTime = getStartTimeOfToday();
        long endTime = startTime + ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;

        HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest.Builder()
                .setDataType(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE)
                .setProperties(new String[] {HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE})
                .setLocalTimeRange(HealthConstants.HeartRate.START_TIME, HealthConstants.HeartRate.TIME_OFFSET,
                        startTime, endTime)
                .build();

        try {
            resolver.read(request).setResultListener(mListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("*&*&*&", "Getting Heart fails.", e);
        }
    }

    private long getStartTimeOfToday() {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return today.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private final HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<HealthDataResolver.ReadResult> mListener = result -> {
        int count = 0;

        try {
            for (HealthData data : result) {
                count += data.getInt(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE);
            }
        } finally {
            result.close();
        }

        if (mHeartRateObserver != null) {
            mHeartRateObserver.onChanged(count);
        }
    };

    private final HealthDataObserver mObserver = new HealthDataObserver(null) {

        @Override
        public void onChange(String dataTypeName) {
            Log.d("*&*&*&", "Observer receives a data changed event");
            readHeartRate();
        }
    };

    public interface HeartRateObserver {
        void onChanged(int count);
    }
}
```

StepCountReporter

```
/**
 * Copyright (C) 2014 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Mobile Communication Division,
 * Digital Media & Communications Business, Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.
 *
 * This software and its documentation are confidential and proprietary
 * information of Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.  No part of the software and
 * documents may be copied, reproduced, transmitted, translated, or reduced to
 * any electronic medium or machine-readable form without the prior written
 * consent of Samsung Electronics.
 *
 * Samsung Electronics makes no representations with respect to the contents,
 * and assumes no responsibility for any errors that might appear in the
 * software and documents. This publication and the contents hereof are subject
 * to change without notice.
 */

package com.example.smaunghealth;

import android.util.Log;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.*;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.healthdata.HealthDataResolver.ReadResult;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class StepCountReporter {

    private final HealthDataStore mStore;
    private StepCountObserver mStepCountObserver;
    private static final long ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;

    public StepCountReporter(HealthDataStore store) {
        mStore = store;
    }

    public void start(StepCountObserver listener) {
        mStepCountObserver = listener;
        // Register an observer to listen changes of step count and get today step count
        HealthDataObserver.addObserver(mStore, HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, mObserver);
        readTodayStepCount();
    }

    // Read the today's step count on demand
    private void readTodayStepCount() {
        HealthDataResolver resolver = new HealthDataResolver(mStore, null);

        // Set time range from start time of today to the current time
        long startTime = getStartTimeOfToday();
        long endTime = startTime + ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;

        HealthDataResolver.ReadRequest request = new ReadRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataType(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE)
                    .setProperties(new String[] {HealthConstants.StepCount.COUNT})
                    .setLocalTimeRange(HealthConstants.StepCount.START_TIME, HealthConstants.StepCount.TIME_OFFSET,
                            startTime, endTime)
                    .build();

        try {
            resolver.read(request).setResultListener(mListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Getting step count fails.", e);
        }
    }

    private long getStartTimeOfToday() {
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        return today.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    private final HealthResultHolder.ResultListener<ReadResult> mListener = result -> {
        int count = 0;

        try {
            for (HealthData data : result) {
                count += data.getInt(HealthConstants.StepCount.COUNT);
            }
        } finally {
            result.close();
        }

        if (mStepCountObserver != null) {
            mStepCountObserver.onChanged(count);
        }
    };

    private final HealthDataObserver mObserver = new HealthDataObserver(null) {

        // Update the step count when a change event is received
        @Override
        public void onChange(String dataTypeName) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.APP_TAG, "Observer receives a data changed event");
            readTodayStepCount();
        }
    };

    public interface StepCountObserver {
        void onChanged(int count);
    }
}
```

Here is the exception log :

[image]

Comment: plz attach the whole log so that we can tell which line throw the exception.

Comment: Done the screen shoot added

Comment: @MuneerahRashed you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.health.permission.read"
               android:value="com.samsung.health.step_count;com.samsung.health.heart_rate"/>
```

I think you should separate this permission into two， not only one。

like：

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.health.permission.read"
               android:value="com.samsung.health.step_count"/>
         <meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.health.permission.read"
               android:value="com.samsung.health.heart_rate"/>
```

Comment: this create deferent error : Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs , in there documentation they mention this way when declaring multiple values https://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/health/index.html?com/samsung/android/sdk/healthdata/HealthPermissionManager.html

Answer (score 0):

After long time finally I was able to address the issue :

```
mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));
        mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEART_RATE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));
```

this is the write permissionKey :

```
mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.StepCount.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));
    mKeySet.add(new HealthPermissionManager.PermissionKey(HealthConstants.HeartRate.HEALTH_DATA_TYPE, HealthPermissionManager.PermissionType.READ));
```